# Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit) addons broken

Tags: firefox

Ive used Firefox for years, but in a recient update, Firefox Quantum, disabled all of my Firefox addons. The addon page in Firefox  shows a link to a Firefox help page that states the reason. "Only extensions built using WebExtensions APIs will work. ." At the bottom of the page it gives a work around. Set; `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false in `about:config`. I was able to reinstall one addon, Video DownloadHelper, but the rest I try to reinstall gives me a message in a red box, `Download failed. Please check your connection.` Is there something else I can do before I try a different browser?

@Gerowen, The link is usefull although I had already uninstalled my addons. After enabling studies, it didn't change my firefox , it shows no active studies, and I'm unable to download addons. It's good to know that the issue is being addressed though.

update...I made `xpinstall.signatures.required` false in `about:config`, and enabled studies `Allow Firefox to install and run studies` in Preferences/Privacy and Security settings section. In about an hour the bugfix showed up in `View Firefox studies` link, so Mozilla is fixing this.
http://tinypic.com/r/35clncx/9
I reinstalled the addons, re-enabled `xpinstall.signatures.required`, and unchecked `Allow Firefox to install and run studies`, and `Allow Firefox to send technical and interaction data to Mozilla`. All of my addons seem to be working properly.

I ran into same issue on a laptop with Firefox, and was able to receive the hotfixes from mozilla without modifying `xpinstall.signatures.required` value.

Dell Optiplex 7040, Ubuntu 18.1, Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been acknowledged by Mozilla, and a fix has been released as a "study" that should automatically install itself if you have them enabled in Firefox's settings.

Here's the blog post discussing the issue and the fix:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/05/04/update-regarding-add-ons-in-firefox/

Comment: I just ran accross this site. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Firefox-Add-Ons-Cert-Expired

Comment: It took about an hour for the study/s to show up.                                                                                          http://tinypic.com/r/35clncx/9

Comment: Funny thing, my "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" addon was still borked.  I could enable it and whatnot, but after this incident it blocks all internet traffic within Firefox and no longer functions properly, :-(

Comment: I don't like the way I have to enable `Allow Firefox to send technical and interaction data to Mozilla`. I always disabled this in the past. It contradicts anonymity.

Comment: This solution was good but is now obsolete because it is now enough to make sure your Firefox is up to date.

Comment: @geras You may be correct concerning this specific issue, although I had Auto-Updates enabled before all of this occured yet it still happened to me. Not to mention learning of the mechanism the programmers use to launch bug fixes. I wouldn't call that obsolete.

Comment: @joeRag yes, this solution is obsolete only for this particular issue and it wasn't obsolete for it earlier when this issue first occurred--then it wasn't enough to have your Firefox up-to-date, only since later it has been enough.